# Image binding wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to generate one element that alows me to show some images into a `treeview` using WPF. I sopose that I have to generate my own `TreeViewItem` in order to bind the properties I want into the `TreeView` control. This is my own `TreeViewItem`:

```
public class TreeViewItem : System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem
{
    public ImageSource Image { get; set; }

    public TreeViewItem(string text, ImageSource displayedImage)
    {
        this.Header = text;
        this.Image = displayedImage;
    }
}
```

With this object generated, I define the structure of my custom TreeView in order to bind all data:

```
<UserControl x:Class="test.TreeControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="100">

<Grid>
    <TreeView Name="TVTree" x:FieldModifier="public">            
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">                    
                <Grid Margin="2" MinHeight="25" MaxHeight="25" MinWidth="60">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="16"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Image}" Height="16" Width="16"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Header}" Margin="5,0"/>
                </Grid>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

As long as I know, I'm trying to bind the Image Source with the image source of my custom control, and the text of the textblock with the header of my `treeviewItem`. The problem is that the control doesn't display the image and I find out that the header is not beeing displayed too. It only displays the result of `ToString()` method (which is the same as the string defined as the Header of the object).

Anybody knows how can I bind this data correctly?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When you use data templates, you need to define your data as type e.g. `TreeItem` and its appearance in a template, here a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for a `TreeView`. A `TreeItem` could look like this.

```
public class TreeItem
{
   public string Header { get; }

   public ImageSource Image { get; }

   public ObservableCollection<TreeItem> Children { get; }

   public TreeItem(string header, ImageSource displayedImage, ObservableCollection<TreeItem> children)
   {
      Header = header;
      Image = displayedImage;
      Children = children;
   }
}
```

You do not inherit from `TreeViewItem`, because you define *data*. A `TreeViewItem` is a *container* in the view that wraps your data template as an item of the `TreeView`. In a `TreeView` there is a hierarchy of items, so you must provide a collection of subitems for any item. This collection can be `null` or empty if there are no further items.

Then you need a view model for your user control which exposes a collection of `TreeItems` that you can bind to. I just created a list of dummy data with three nested items in `Children` collections to show the hierarchy.

```
public class TreeControlViewModel
{
   public ObservableCollection<TreeItem> TreeItems { get; }

   public TreeControlViewModel()
   {
      TreeItems = new ObservableCollection<TreeItem>
      {
         new TreeItem("Item 1", null, null),
         new TreeItem("Item 2", null, null),
         new TreeItem("Item 3", null, null),
         new TreeItem("Item 4", null, new ObservableCollection<TreeItem>
         {
            new TreeItem("Item 41", null, null),
            new TreeItem("Item 42", null, new ObservableCollection<TreeItem>
            {
               new TreeItem("Item421", null, null)
            })
         }),
         new TreeItem("Item 5", null, null)
      };

   }
}
```

Next you have to create an instance of the `TreeControlViewModel` and assign it to the `TreeControl` user control, so you can bind to its `TreeItems` property, which is the collection for the `TreeView`.

```
<UserControl x:Class="test.TreeControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="200"
             d:DesignWidth="100">
   <UserControl.DataContext>
      <local:TreeControlViewModel/>
   </UserControl.DataContext>

   <!-- ...your tree view XAML code. -->

</UserControl
```

At last, be sure to actually bind to the `TreeItems` collection via `ItemsSource`, otherwise no items are displayed.

```
<TreeView Name="TVTree" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}">
```

As a note, `ObservableCollection` will notify and trigger updating the `TreeView` when you modify the collection of items with e.g. `Add` or `Remove`. If you are interested in modifiying properties like `Header`, too, you should have a look at `INotifyPropertyChanged` an [how it is implemented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface) to enable updates for them in the user interface, too. For the sake of simplicity and focus on your issue I will skip this part.

Answer (score 0):

Your bindings are looking for an `Image` and `Header` in the `DataContext`, which would be your **VM** in standard MVVM WPF. If you check your output window in Visual Studio you will see binding errors to that effect.

You do not need your `TreeViewItem` class, you are already defining the view for a tree item with your template.

You do need a `TreeItemVM` to bind to. Add your properties in there instead. They should be data only. No visual classes.